# Chrome extension: Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension, with the manifest.json file below:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "JIRA bug Recorder",
    "description": "",
    "background": { "service_worker": "background.bundle.js" },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "Icon32.png"
    },
    "icons": {
        "32": "Icon32.png",
        "128": "Icon128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "contextMenus",
        "webNavigation",
        "tabs",
        "desktopCapture"
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["pageContent.bundle.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I click on the extension icon to show the popup.html, I get the following error on the extension.

[image]

I noticed that if I remove the `host_permissions` and `content_scripts` fields from the manifest.json, then the error disappeared.

I am not sure why, as none of my scripts set cross site cookies, including `pageContent.bundle.js`.

Does anyone know how to fix or suppress this?

Answer (score 0):

This is warning not error, google noting that we should Prepare for third-party cookies restrictions.
here detail explanation: [Prepare for phasing out third-party cookies](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd#report-issues)